# Can't Create Matplotlib Figures from Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder, fedora

It's been about one week since experimenting with a project I've been working in python.  I'm running fedora 33 and use spyder 4.1.5 for the development environment.  After returning to the project today and installing standard updates, I suddenly I can't create figures with matplotlib.  I've been tinkering with python in this manner on and off for years and this is the first time I've run into this issue.

I've also tried getting around the issue by doing the following:

1. I've tried changing the python interpreter in spyder from 3.9 to 3.8 with no luck.
2. I've also tried changing the graphics backend in spyder from PyQt5 to PyQt4 but if I do that then I get a different error.  This used to work so something has changed.
3. The final thing I've tried is launching the code from a terminal via `python3 test.py` and that works fine!  I just can't debug or really do much more with spyder other than use it as basic text editor.

Below is a simple example of trying to create a figure and then the error message that I receive.

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Aug 30 2021, 00:00:00) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Gtk-Message: 08:33:31.853: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"

>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

>> plt.figure()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-65b822729fc4>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.figure()

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 687, in figure
    figManager = new_figure_manager(num, figsize=figsize,

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 315, in new_figure_manager
    return _backend_mod.new_figure_manager(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3494, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3499, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    canvas = cls.FigureCanvas(figure)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(figure=figure)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 219, in __init__
    _create_qApp()

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 126, in _create_qApp
    qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(["matplotlib"])

  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 160, in __init__
    super(SpyderQApplication, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Here is the error message I get when changing the graphics backend from PyQt5 to PyQt4.

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Aug 30 2021, 00:00:00) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

=========================================================================
NOTE: The following error appeared when setting your Matplotlib backend!!
=========================================================================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/console/kernel.py", line 580, in _set_mpl_backend
    get_ipython().run_line_magic(magic, backend)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2326, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-108>", line 2, in matplotlib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 187, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py", line 99, in matplotlib
    gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui.lower() if isinstance(args.gui, str) else args.gui)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3505, in enable_matplotlib
    pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py", line 320, in activate_matplotlib
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2336, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 276, in switch_backend
    class backend_mod(matplotlib.backend_bases._Backend):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 277, in backend_mod
    locals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(backend_name)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg'
```

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/)

Comment: I think this is an error that only shows up in Fedora. So please another distro or Anaconda, as already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I probably could have done this with Fedora, but I recently switched to Ubuntu and still had issues with Spyder and matplotlib (although not the same issues).  I found a solution to my problem in the thread linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114520/error-when-starting-spyder-on-ubuntu-22-04) in one of the comments.  Because I don't have enough reputation on stackoverflow yet, I can't comment directly in that thread.

I followed Carlos Cordoba's suggestion and created a python virtualenv. The link on how to do this is [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment).

After setting up the virtualenv, I installed spyder 3.5.1 via
`python3 -m pip install spyder`

The I installed numpy, scipy and matplotlib via pip in the same manner.  By default the latest version of matplotlib was installed, which was version 3.5.2.  Matplotlib 3.5.2 still did not work for me (again a different issue than previously experienced)!  However, I found that downgrading to 3.5.0 seems to be working so far though.  You can install matplotlib 3.5.0 via
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib==3.5.0`

I did not try matplotlib 3.5.1, but so far at least spyder 3.5.1 seems to be compatible with matplotlib 3.5.0.