# error when starting spyder on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, spyder, upgrade, ubuntu-22.04

I have just upgrade my ubuntu. I have this error on spyder:

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('spyder==4.2.1', 'gui_scripts', 'spyder')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 213, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3624, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(app, splash, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3482, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 803, in setup
    self.completions = CompletionManager(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/plugin.py", line 97, in __init__
    plugin_client = Plugin(self.main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/plugin.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.installer = KiteInstallerDialog(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py", line 287, in __init__
    self._integration_widget = KiteIntegrationInfo(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py", line 58, in __init__
    image = image.scaled(image_width, image_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  scaled(self, int, int, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  scaled(self, QSize, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

All the solution that I have found deal with specific application developed my different user and not for probel related to upgrade or ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try what the first line told you to do?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean. QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland in terminal does not work.

Answer (score 9):

As a quick workaround just comment out the lines in File:

> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py

58

```
#image = image.scaled(image_width, image_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
```

143

```
#install_gif.setScaledSize(QSize(image_width, image_height))
```

244-247

```
#copilot_label.setPixmap(
            #    copilot_image.scaled(image_width, image_height,
            #                         Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
            #                         Qt.SmoothTransformation))
```

Comment: In my case, I just commented all the cases where I received an error in install.py, which were not exactly these lines...After this, it worked

Answer (score 6):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The Spyder package provided by Ubuntu 22.04 (**4.2.1**, released in December 2020) is broken with the Python version that comes with it (**3.10**).

However, this error was fixed in Spyder **5.3.0**, released in March 2022. So, to solve this problem please uninstall the Spyder that comes with Ubuntu and install it with pip in a virtualenv, as explained in [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#using-pip).

Comment: Installation worked but it does not run because still something seems missing.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, did a search with the following two items :

"spyder" + "mainwindow.py, line 3624"     # aka a piece of the error message

I found the bug report #16571 on spyder's github : "TypeError in Tour with Python 3.10", which identified python 3.10 as the culprit.

In Debian + aptitude I downgraded python 3 from 3.10 to the 3.9 version, launched Spyder again and...problem solved !